# Flutter CustomScrollView and Scoped model problems

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm facing some issues quite the time lately. I'm using the [scoped_model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model) package for my application. But i'm getting the problem that when i'm searching for stuff or i turn my screen to landscape modus it builds twice.

When this happens i'm getting duplicate json because it is rebuilding twice.

I'm getting another issue when i have searched and i go back my custom scroll view is not working anymore. I can't scroll down anymore.

I have writtin the following files:

**main.dart:**

```
class GetRelations extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RelationsPage createState() => RelationsPage();
}

class RelationsPage extends State<GetRelations> {
  final RelationScopedModel relationScopedModel = RelationScopedModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    relationScopedModel.initializeValues();

    return Scaffold(
      body: ScopedModel<RelationScopedModel>(
        model: relationScopedModel,
        child: Container(
          child: SearchScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**search_screen.dart:**

```
class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SearchScreenState createState() {
    return new SearchScreenState();
  }
}

class SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  final RelationScopedModel relationScopedModel = RelationScopedModel();
  ScrollController controller;
  int page = 0;
  bool atEnd = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    var props = RelationScopedModel.of(context);

    /// When reload we check if skip == 0, if skip is 0 then page has to become 0 too.
    if (props.skip == 0) {
      page = 0;
    }

    /// Checking if user is at the end of the screen, then let's receive some new content.
    if (controller.position.pixels == controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      /// If it is at the end, we have to set atEnd to true.
      if (props.atTheEnd == true) {
        atEnd = props.atTheEnd;
        return;
      }

      /// If it has no more pages, return.
      if (props.hasMorePages == false) {
        return;
      }

      /// If it is has more stuff, load it in!
      if (!props.isLoadingMore && props.hasMorePages) {
        page++;
        props.getRelations(props.search, page);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Go back to last page by using WillPopScope.
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: new Scaffold(
        drawer: new DrawerOnly(),

        /// We are using Scoped Model to load the json in the sliver list.
        body: ScopedModelDescendant<RelationScopedModel>(
          builder: (context, child, model) {
            return CustomScrollView(
              controller: controller,
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  title: SearchWidget(
                    performSearch: model.getRelations,
                  ),
                  floating: true,
                  pinned: true,
                ),
                model.isLoading && model.atTheEnd
                    ? SliverFillRemaining(
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      )
                    : model.getRelationCount() < 1
                        ? SliverFillRemaining(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                model.statusText,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : SliverList(
                            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                              (context, index) {
                                if (index == model.getRelationCount() + 1) {
                                  if (model.hasMorePages == true) {
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 16.0),
                                      child: Center(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                    );
                                  }
                                  return Container(width: 0, height: 0);
                                } else if (index == 0) {
                                  return Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border(
                                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.grey[300]))),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Relaties",
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .body2
                                          .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        InkWell(
                                          child: RelationItem(
                                              model.relation[index - 1]),
                                          onTap: () {
                                            var id =
                                                model.relation[index - 1].id;
                                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (BuildContext
                                                            context) =>
                                                        new DetailScreen(id)));
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                              childCount: model.getRelationCount() + 2,
                            ),
                          )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**search.dart (this is my searchwidget):**

```
class SearchWidget extends StatelessWidget {   final performSearch;

  const SearchWidget({Key key, @required this.performSearch}) : super(key: key);

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('wat gebeurt er');
    return Card(
      elevation: 3.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: "Zoeken..."),
                onChanged: (String search) {
                  if (search.length > 2) {
                    performSearch(search);
                  }
                  if (search.length == 0) {
                    performSearch(search);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsScreen()));
              },
              child: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.slidersH,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );   } }
```

**relation_scoped_model.dart:**

```
class RelationScopedModel extends Model {
  List<GetRelation> _relation = [];
  List<GetContacts> _contacts = [];
  List<GetLocations> _locations = [];
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String _statusText = "Start met zoeken...";
  bool _hasMorePages = true;
  int _skip = 0;
  int skipMore = 0;
  String _search;
  bool _isLoadingMore = false;
  bool atTheEnd = false;

  List<Map<String, String>> _listingTypeList = [
    {"name": "Buy", "value": "buy"},
    {"name": "Rent", "value": "rent"},
  ];
  String _listingType;

  List<Map<String, String>> _sortList = [
    {"name": "Relevancy", "value": "relevancy"},
    {"name": "Bedroom (Ascending)", "value": "bedroom_lowhigh"},
    {"name": "Bedroom (Descending)", "value": "bedroom_highlow"},
    {"name": "Price (Ascending)", "value": "price_lowhigh"},
    {"name": "Price (Descending)", "value": "price_highlow"},
    {"name": "Newest", "value": "newest"},
    {"name": "Oldest", "value": "oldest"},
    {"name": "Random", "value": "random"},
    {"name": "Distance", "value": "distance"}
  ];

  String _sort;

  List<GetRelation> get relation => _relation;

  List<GetContacts> get contacts => _contacts;

  List<GetLocations> get locations => _locations;

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  String get statusText => _statusText;

  bool get hasMorePages => _hasMorePages;

  String get search => _search;

  int get skip => _skip;

  bool get isLoadingMore => _isLoadingMore;

  List<Map<String, String>> get listingTypeList => _listingTypeList;

  String get listingType => _listingType;

  List<Map<String, String>> get sortList => _sortList;

  String get sort => _sort;

  int getRelationCount() => _relation.length;

  void initializeValues() async {
    _relation.clear();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _listingType = prefs.getString('listingType') ?? 'rent';
    _sort = prefs.getString('sort') ?? 'relevancy';
    getRelations(search);
  }

  var _skiptotal = 10;
  var lastSearch;

  Future<dynamic> _getData(String search, [int page = 0]) async {

    /// When page is 0 we don't have to skip content, if page is 1 or higher it will have to skip content
    if (page != 0) {
      var skipPage = page * _skiptotal;
      _skip = skipPage;
    }

    /// If page == 0, we have to set page and _skip to 0.
    else {
      _skip = 0;
      page = 0;
    }

    /// When nothing is filled in the input search, we have to set search to single quotes because otherwise it will search on null.
    if (search == null) {
      search = '';
    }

    if (lastSearch != search) {
      _relation.clear();
      lastSearch = '';
      lastSearch = search;
      page + 1;
    }

    String _credentials;
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _credentials = (pref.getString("credentials") ?? "Empty");

    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("$cf_api_RelationsUrl" +
            "?$cf_api_SkipParameter=$_skip&$cf_api_SearchParameter=$search&$cf_api_LimitParameter=10"),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "accept": "application/json",
          'cookie': '$_credentials'
        });

    var decodedJson = json.decode(res.body, reviver: (k, v) {
      if (k == "status" && v == false) {
        _hasMorePages = false;
        return v;
      } else {
        return v;
      }
    });

    if (_hasMorePages == false) {
      return decodedJson;
    } else {
      List list = List();
      list = json.decode(res.body) as List;
      if (list.length < 10) {
        atTheEnd = true;
        _hasMorePages = false;
        return decodedJson;
      }
    }

    return decodedJson;
  }

  Future getRelations(String search, [int page = 0]) async {
    if (page == 0) {
      page = 0;
      _isLoading = true;
      _relation.clear();
    } else {
      _isLoadingMore = true;
    }

    _search = search;
    var responseData = await _getData(search, page);
    notifyListeners();

    var result = responseData
        .map(
            (data) => serializers.deserializeWith(GetRelation.serializer, data))
        .toList();

    result.forEach((relations) {
      _relation.add(relations);
    });

    if (result.isEmpty) {
      _statusText = "Nothing Found";
    }

    if (page == 0) {
      _isLoading = false;
    } else {
      _isLoadingMore = false;
    }

    if (atTheEnd == true) {
      return true;
    }

//    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setListingType(String value) async {
    _listingType = value;
    getRelations(search);
    notifyListeners();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('listingType', _listingType);
  }

  void setSort(String value) async {
    _sort = value;
    getRelations(search);
    notifyListeners();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('sort', _sort);
  }

  /// Wraps [ScopedModel.of] for this [Model].
  static RelationScopedModel of(BuildContext context) =>
      ScopedModel.of<RelationScopedModel>(context);
}
```

I'm guessing that the problem is that my scopedmodeldescendant isn't in the init state. But i'm not sure and i hope somebody knows what the problem is with this code.

Thanks in advance

Greetings,

Jente

**UPDATE:**
I got my customscrollview is working when i set atTheEnd to false and hasMorePages to true in my relation_scoped_model at initializeValues().

The only problem i'm still facing is that i'm getting duplicates, which happens because my screen is rebuilding twice.

Answer (score 0):

When using scoped model, you should wrap the widgets that should respond to changes one by one with scoped model descendants. This way only those widgets can rebuild rather than the whole page rebuilding.